# Multitouch with four button

Tags: android, multi-touch

Hi everyone I am creating an application that controls a car with an Arduino. I have four touch buttons, one forward, one backward, one left and one right. I don't understand how to use multitouch with these 4 buttons.

This is the code of the forward and left buttons:

```
//Forward
     btFrente.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    envia("0");
                    return true;
                }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    envia("1");
                    return true;    
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

         //Left 
         btEsquerda.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    envia("0");
                    return true;
                }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    envia("3");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Envia is used to send the number to the arduino. I do need to send another number when I click on front button and left at the same time, for example. I need to do the same for front right, back left and back right.

How can I do this?